# Adding image to MKAnnotationView displaces pin

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I'm trying to drop some pins that represent bus stops with an image, when I ad the image it changes the placement of the pin. When I do not set an image the pin is dropped in the correct place.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

    if annotation is StopAnnotation {

        let identifier = "stopAnnotation"
        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier)
        if pinView == nil {
            //println("Pinview was nil")
            pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            pinView!.canShowCallout = true
            pinView.image = UIImage(named: "stopIcon")
        }
        return pinView

    }
    return nil
}
```

Examples
[image]
[image]

The image I am trying to use: 
[image]

Can anyone tell me why this is doing this? I am using the exact same image in my Obj-C version of this app and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is creating an `MKPinAnnotationView` with a custom image.

The `MKPinAnnotationView` class should only be used to display the default pin images.

To show a custom image, it's better to use a plain `MKAnnotationView`.

Because the code is using an `MKPinAnnotationView`, the image is automatically getting an offset applied to it (the `centerOffset` property).

This built-in offset works for the default pin images but not for your custom image.

Rather than trying to override this default behavior, use a plain `MKAnnotationView` instead:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

    if annotation is StopAnnotation {

        let identifier = "stopAnnotation"
        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier)
        if pinView == nil {
            //println("Pinview was nil")

            //Create a plain MKAnnotationView if using a custom image... 
            pinView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)

            pinView!.canShowCallout = true
            pinView.image = UIImage(named: "stopIcon")
        }
        else {
            //Unrelated to the image problem but...
            //Update the annotation reference if re-using a view...
            pinView.annotation = annotation
        }

        return pinView          
    }
    return nil
}
```